Calculate camera extrinsic matrix from homography
I am trying to derive the 3D projection matrix in Python/OpenCV for a camera from a homography and the focal length. I derived these from detected marker points and the view angle. Is this possible, and if so what am I doing wrong?
Using Python 3.12.2 & OpenCV 4.9.0
import numpy as np
import cv2

hfov_degrees = 60
image_dim = [640, 480]

marker = np.array([[0, 0, 0], # world coordinates
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.float32)

detection = np.array([[220, 140], # pixel coordinates
                      [420, 140],
                      [420, 340],
                      [220, 340]], dtype=np.float32)

f = image_dim[0] / (2 * np.tan(np.radians(hfov_degrees / 2))) # focal length
K = np.array([[f, 0, image_dim[0] / 2], # intrinsic matrix K
              [0, f, image_dim[1] / 2],
              [0, 0, 1]])
H, _ = cv2.findHomography(marker[:,0:2], detection) # homography
n, R, t, _ = cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(H, K) # rotation & translation

for i in range(n): # trying each solution
    rotation = R[i]/ np.linalg.norm(R[i])
    translation = t[i].reshape(3, 1)
    Rt = np.hstack((rotation, translation)) # extrinsic matrix
    P = np.dot(K, Rt) # projection matrix
    
    points = np.hstack((marker, np.ones((marker.shape[0], 1)))) # append ones to test
    points = np.dot(P, points.T).T
    result = points[:, :2] / points[:, 2][:, None]
    print(result)

I tested my code by trying to project the same real-world marker coordinates that I used to find the homography, back to the image plane. I verified homography H is correct. However "decomposeHomographyMat" returns 4 solutions, but none of them results in sensible coordinates.
